# Laravel: Better way to update database (one liner)?

Tags: laravel

So, I'm looking to do an update on a MySQL database and this is my current update code:

```
    $currentMinute = Carbon::now();
    $nextMinute = $currentMinute->copy()->addMinute();

    $transfersWithinRange = Account::whereBetween('next_vc_transfer', [$currentMinute, $nextMinute])->get(); 

    if (count($transfersWithinRange) > 0) {
        foreach ($transfersWithinRange as $transfer) {
            $transfer->balance = $transfer->balance + 0.25;
            $transfer->next_vc_transfer = Carbon::parse($transfer->next_vc_transfer)->addMinutes(15);
            $transfer->save();
        }
    }
```

My boss said there was a one liner for this. I was thinking something like this:

```
 Account::increment('balance', .25, ['next_vc_transfer' => Carbon::parse($transfer->next_vc_transfer)->addMinute(15)]).whereBetween('next_vc_transfer', [$currentMinute, $nextMinute]);

// obviously, $transfer won't work with this liner
```

Thoughts?

Comment: I think I see a typo on your code:
 Account::increment('balance', .25, ['next_vc_transfer' => Carbon::parse($transfer->next_vc_transfer)->addMinute(15)])->whereBetween('next_vc_transfer', [$currentMinute, $nextMinute]);

Changed the '.' to a '->'

Comment: Thanks, I'm coming from JavaScript mentality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, this is what I came up with for a one liner:

```
 Account::whereBetween('next_vc_transfer_at', [$currentMinute, $nextMinute])
     ->update([
         'balance' => DB::raw('balance + 0.25'),
         'next_vc_transfer_at' => $newVCTransferAt
     ]);
```